# Is it possible to create react native library and refer in the new react native project without uploading to npm

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are creating few components with react native and we want to use those in multiple react native project within our organization is it possible to create some reusable library and refer in multiple react native app without uploading to npm.

We need to share some common react native components without shipping the entire code.?

is there any way to achieve this .?

Answer (score 0):

I think `npm link` maybe help you.

Assume you created some components in folder `library` folder. In this folder, you have `package.json` file. You can put your source to github or bitbucket, gitlap. The following structure like that.

```html
--your library folder
 |-- some stuff files
 |-- package.json
```

And in your project, you can create a new folder like `external_library` and put your library source in it. To use it for your library. From root folder go to your library like.

```
cd external_library
```

Link your library to npm.

```
npm link
```

Now, this library has the name `external_library` like the name of `folder`. Go back root folder and like this library to your project

```
cd ../
```

Link this library to your project

```
npm link external_library
```

Now you can be using all component of your library.

Comment: i don't want to publish the code to the repo like bit/npm. Is it possible with npm/Bit .?

Comment: Bitbucket is a private repo. If you can't push your code to the repo so I don't know how to share.